Not able to see document/page after login using Azure AD b2c authentication
When I click on sign up, it supposed to be redirected to http://localhost:7225/home since I have added this as Redirect URL in azure portal which seems to be fine till here, but still getting that

localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Using MSAL.js
Here is the configuration file


import { PublicClientApplication, LogLevel } from "@azure/msal-browser";

export const b2cPolicies = {
  names: {
    signUpSignIn: "B2C_1_susi",
    resetPassword: "B2C_1_Reset",
  },
  authorities: {
    signUpSignIn: {
      authority: "https://abc.b2clogin.com/xyz.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_susi",
    }
  },
};

export const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: "00000000000000",
    authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.signUpSignIn.authority,
    knownAuthorities: ["xyz.b2clogin.com"],
     redirectUri: "http://localhost:7225/home",
     postLogoutRedirectUri: "https://localhost:7225/",
    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
  },
  system: {
    loggerOptions: {
      loggerCallback: (level: any, message: any, containsPii: any) => {
        if (containsPii) return;
        switch (level) {
          case LogLevel.Error:
            console.error(`MSAL Error: ${message}`);
            break;
          case LogLevel.Warning:
            console.warn(`MSAL Warning: ${message}`);
            break;
          case LogLevel.Info:
            console.info(`MSAL Info: ${message}`);
            break;
          case LogLevel.Verbose:
            console.debug(`MSAL Verbose: ${message}`);
            break;
          default:
            console.log(`MSAL: ${message}`);
            break;
        }
      },
      piiLoggingEnabled: false, 
      logLevel: LogLevel.Verbose, 
    },
  },
};
export const loginRequest = {
  scopes: ["openid", "offline_access"],
};
export const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
  



Index.tsx


root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
     <Provider store={store}>
      <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
        <ApolloProvider client={graphqlclient}>
           <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </ApolloProvider>
        </MsalProvider>
     </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();



App.tsx (this is how i call the login page from Azure Ad b2cimage link)


useEffect(() => {
    if (accounts.length === 0) {
            msalInstance.loginRedirect({
              scopes: ["openid"],
              authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.signUpSignIn.authority,
              redirectUri: "http://localhost:7225/home",
            });
          } 

      const callbackId = instance.addEventCallback((event:any) => {
      if (
        (event.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS || event.eventType === EventType.ACQUIRE_TOKEN_SUCCESS) &&
        event.payload?.account
      ) {
        const account = event.payload.account;
        instance.setActiveAccount(account); 
      }

      if (event.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_FAILURE) {
        if (event.error && event.error.errorMessage.includes('AADB2C90118')) {
          const resetPasswordRequest = {
            authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.resetPassword.authority,
            scopes: [], 
          };
          instance.loginRedirect(resetPasswordRequest);
        }
      } 
    });
    return () => {
      if (callbackId) { 
        instance.removeEventCallback(callbackId);
      }
    };
  }, [instance]);

 




Could you check if you’re getting any console errors?

What port is your app running on?

no console errors are present, instead, checked network tab which says "failed to load response data"
port:7225
